# Cannot install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to an external HDD

Tags: system-installation, external-hdd

**The problem:** I want to install Ubuntu on my HDD, but after the installation process from the Installation-USB, the HDD won't boot up and does not get shown as possible boot device.

I have a 5TB WD Elements HDD. I have yet no storage on it so I can totally mess around at that HDD. Since I want to use 4,8TB of my HDD for pure storage (exFAT) and only 200GB for Ubuntu, I pre-partioned the HDD that way.

In the Ubuntu installation progress, running from a live-USB-Stick, I choosed "something else" as an option, formatted the 200GB to ext4, primary, / as root and below my external HDD as device for the bootloader. Finished the installation, rebooted and no device was found.

I also tried other stuff:

```
Preformatting in gparted

Creating an additional swap-partition of something like 10GB (always used different sizes from 5-10GB)

Creating an additional bios-partition

Using the 200GB partition for the bootloader instead of the whole drive

Using the whole drive as an installation medium (not preformatting it myself)

Trying to boot up the HDD on different computers
```

There probably seems to be a problem that the boot partition is not working or something like that. The system partition seems to exist and the installation progress was always finished successfully (until the reboot)

I successfully did several installations of Ubuntu before on internal HDDs. So I am wondering why this is not working on my portable HDD. Neverless what I do, neverless what tutorial or forum post I read, I did not get it to work. I did at least 10 full installations. I just want a portable HDD that can boot up while beeing connected at any PC.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: Confirm that you put the bootloader on the external drive, (sdx not sdx1), and not on the USB or internal disk. It is a good idea to unplug the internal drive if it is not too difficult. disable Safe Boot and other Microsoft  stuff if applicable. Install to external in same BIOS/UEFI mode as internal drive boots in.

Comment: I physically disconnected every drive existing on the PC, the only ones left were the installation-USB and my external HDD. I tried both sdx and sdx1.

Comment: Can you try the external on a different PC?

Comment: Also did not work, already wrote that in my question. Depends on which setting. Do I need to create the swap disk or not?

Comment: I also just followed along to this: https://www.58bits.com/blog/2020/02/28/how-create-truly-portable-ubuntu-installation-external-usb-hdd-or-ssd step-by-step until E, but it still does not boot up

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? You need either ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot or bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. When first converting from BIOS to UEFI I always added both to every drive & flash drive with full installs. Ubuntu now uses a swap file, so swap partition not required, but will be used if found. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: I used BIOS for installation. In the end I want it to run on both BIOS and UEFI, I dont know if this sounds stupid but can you install two boot partitions? (One for BIOS, another one for UEFI to boot up on nearly every PC system). But it should still work since it was only in this BIOS scope. I read your answers on that link you send me and I'm not shure I got it right. So you are saying that when the installation process on the Installation-USB started (After selecting username&password), I should grab the boot partition of the Installation-USB and put it onto the external HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Install Ubuntu from a Pre-built Image File that boots BIOS and UEFI

It looks like you are doing everything right. At this point it might be  worth installing Ubuntu from an image file. The image file will turn tour disk into a clone of a working, external Full install system, that boots in both BIOS and UEFI modes. It is quick and simple and **always works**.

**If working in Windows:**

- Download Image File: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-06-26.img.xz
- Download **Rufus***: https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.11/rufus-3.11.exe
- Double click Rufus exe file.
- Select USB drive as Target drive in Rufus.
- Select above Image File in Rufus.
- Click Rufus start button.
- Wait for flashing to complete... Done.
- Password is "changeme", change it

[image]

The USB drive should boot on almost any modern X86-64 computer.

Thanks to sudodus for the image file.

In Windows it may be necessary to install 7Zip before proceeding. Rufus will use it when working with the .xz image: https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe

**If working in Ubuntu:** you can use **mkusb**, **Disks** or **Etcher** to flash the USB drive. P7zip may be needed to extract the image.

Comment: I will try that out today. Why do I need an SD-Card? Can't I extract the ISO on my HDD partition? I mean I rather want it to run from my HDD and not from an SD-Card

Comment: @ljonja: Oops! should read USB drive, not SD card. This process will work with any USB device, Flash drives, SD cards, HDD's, SSD's, MP3 players, etc.

Comment: Just about to do this. If I get this correctly, I can only flash the whole medium, right? And the whole system will be only as big as the ISO, so about 15GB? Just started the flash process on a small 16GB usb-stick, guess it would be more sense than flashing a whole 5TB medium worth of 15GB of storage

Comment: Yes the image will overwrite the whole disk, on a 5TB disk it will leave 4,985 TB of unformatted space. This unformatted space can be formatted as NTFS. It is probably best to start out installing on a 16GB usb-stick to get the hang of the procedure.

Comment: @ljonja, It is also possible to expand the root partition on the USB drive with `gparted` (when booted from another drive). See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=GrowIt.pdf). -- Or a compromise, expand the root partition, but leave drive space for a separate data partition (with the file system, that you prefer, maybe NTFS, if you want access also from Windows).

Comment: It worked! Installed the ISO on the tiny USB-Stick, did not load on my old big pc but it did work on my MacBook Pro Mid-2012! May not be the fastest and I just grabbed the next best USB stick at home. I think I won't install it to my 5TB HDD and rather keep it on the tiny USB since I want to solely keep the 5TB for backups. Maybe I get a bigger USB Stick someday (like the Samsung MUF USB Sticks) but I will first stick ok this tiny one.

Comment: Thanks to everyone helping me out!

Comment: @ljonja, Congratulations and thanks for sharing your result :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an 8 TB SSD. I wondered if maybe Ubuntu had a problem addressing the large space, so I partitioned the SSD into a 200 GB drive and a 7.8 TB data disk using gparted. This worked. I was able to boot into the Ubuntu partition. Incidentally, the partitioning was done after the Ubuntu installation, so I was assuming that Ubuntu had been installed in the lower disk space. I should think that if the partitioning were done before installation, that would also work.