# Im trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto a 2tb USB stick

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 onto a 2tb USB stick but I keep getting an error that it failed to format a partition as ext4, can someone help me?

Comment: There are some other things to worry about with external USB install in UEFI mode, such as EFI System Partition being misplaced in the internal disk. I have no idea why your 2tb stick won't format. Boot your computer from the installation USB and choose **Try Ubuntu without installing**. Open gparted and try formatting the 2tb USB from there. Edit your question above and report exactly what errors you get.

Comment: Google fake usb 2T stick  and be aware of the smaller (8GB) fakes out there.  the f3 package utilities can check that the size of the stick is accurate.

Comment: You may need to format the disk using the GPT partition scheme. MBRs partition size limit is right at 2TB

Comment: i have checked, and yes, it really is 2tb, even i thought it was a scam at first, but it was real, but im currently trying to clone a 32gb stick i have with ubuntu already on it to the 2tb one, and im gonna see how that turns out

Comment: You could try doing a full Ubuntu install using an image file, The image file will turn your disk into a clone of a working, Full install system, that boots in both BIOS and UEFI modes. It is quick and simple and always works.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291725/cannot-install-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-an-external-hdd/1291883#1291883 The 2GB imae flashes to 15GB. The rest of the disk can be formatted to FAT32 or NTFS and used for data.